# How to enable Singlestore studio in Singlestore Kubernetes Operator

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, singlestore

I deployed a singlestore test cluster using the documentation from https://docs.singlestore.com/db/v7.3/deploy/kubernetes/ on AWS.

The deployment was successful, and I managed to get the cluster up and running and I am able to connect to it via CLI, but for ease of access, we need to connect to the singlestore studio url as well.

My test cluster currently looks like the following :

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
node-sdb-cluster-leaf-1         1/1     Running   0          102m
node-sdb-cluster-master         2/2     Running   0          102m
sdb-operator-deployment-1       1/1     Running   0          102m
```

All the pods are up and running and I am able to perform simple DB query executions on this cluster.

There was no port exposed for 8080 in the default documentation, and so I created a nodeport for the 8080 port and when I tried to connect to the singlestore studio using :

```
http://node-ip:nodeport/connect
```

The browser request is timing out.

Even a curl command inside the master pod to connect to the studio on port 8080 results in a

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to <cluster-master pod ip>:8080; Connection refused
```

How can I enable singlestore studio inside the k8s operator for singlestore.


I am unable to find any relevant documentation or links for this.

Please let me know if I am missing some step in the configuration.

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Thanks.
Have posted it there as well.